# Plpgsql; store all table names into an array

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

My main purpose is actually, filtering all table names contain 'Messdaten' in it (for example "ID: 843063334 CH: 0001 Messdaten") and create new tables out of them with 'create table as' command as 'Backup_Messdaten1', 'Backup_Messdaten2', etc.

First I was trying to store all table names without filtering (there is maybe a way to retrieve all table names, contain 'Messdaten' in it by sql query, I don't know), and then storing the ones contain 'Messdaten' into another array and using that new array in the 'create table as' command.

But as I said my first goal is just to store all table names into an array;

Code itself;

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION retrieve()
RETURNS text[] AS
$BODY$DECLARE
tbl_names text[];
BEGIN
tbl_names := array(SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE 
table_schema='public' AND table_type='BASE TABLE');
SELECT tbl_names[i] FROM generate_subscripts(tbl_names, 1) g(i);
END;$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION retrieve()
OWNER TO postgres;
```

But for the code above, I am getting such an error;

Error;

```
ERROR: could not find array type for data type information_schema.sql_identifier
SQL state: 42704
Context: SQL statement "SELECT array(SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='public' AND table_type='BASE TABLE')"
PL/pgSQL function retrieve() line 4 at assignment
```

Do you have any idea what is wrong with it and by the way I explained my main purpose, I would appreciate it If you point me to the right direction regarding that purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT array_agg(table_name::text)
FROM information_schema.tables
WHERE table_schema='public' AND table_type='BASE TABLE';
```

You need to cast the table name to `text`. The subquery is unnecessary, and you need to use `array_agg` not the `array` pseudo-function.

Personally I don't see why you need to aggregate them into an array at all, though. I'd just:

```
DECLARE
    tablename text;
BEGIN
    FOR tablename IN
      SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables
      WHERE table_schema='public' AND table_type='BASE TABLE'
      AND ... my extra filters here ...
    LOOP
        EXECUTE format('CREATE TABLE %I AS TABLE %I', tablename || '_backup', tablename);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: thanks, it works now. There was actually no point of aggregating them into an array, I just thought it was the only way. I need to read more manual I guess = )

Comment: @mctuna By the way, this is actually a really bad backup strategy. You should be using `pg_dump`, and/or using `pg_basebackup` and streaming replication or PITR, either manually or with a tool like `pgbarman`.

Comment: If you have any suggestion or contradictory for the following case I would be very happy. 
Actually our plan is to dump everything but messdaten tables(messdaten tables are huge, 95% of all database) after that create messdate1234_backup tables just from the data of the previous month and via sed editor editing the file names and their content of messdatenblabla_backup back to the original names (removing _backup from the ends so when we restore it back there wouldnt be any name conflict) and dump&zip them every month as name_YYYYMM.ZIP.

Comment: So instead of dump that huge and constantly growing tables every month from the beginning, select the previous month data and dump&zip just the previous month, seemed to me faster but as I said, I don't know if there is any drawback at that strategy

Comment: If you're just cloning the tables to copy them, instead you should just be doing a `COPY (SELECT ... FROM messdaten WHERE ...) TO '/some/path'`, avoiding creating the table just to dump it.

Comment: in case of need, can I restore them as easily as dump? I guess in that case there will be no insert commands in those copies

Comment: @mctuna You'd restore them with `COPY messdaten FROM '/path/to/copydump/file'` ; this will `INSERT` the rows. So you need a little custom scripting to automate it, but less than with your currently proposed approach.

Answer (score 2):

Your code contains more errors - basic error is missing any RETURN statement (for PL/pgSQL language). You can use SQL language too (see my example)

Postgres doesn't support arrays for some types - sql_identifier is one. You can try to use a casting to some basic type - in this case to text.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION names(filter text)
RETURNS text[] AS $$
   SELECT array_agg(table_name::text)
      FROM information_schema.tables
     WHERE table_schema='public'
       AND table_type='BASE TABLE' AND table_name LIKE $1;
$$ LANGUAGE sql;

postgres=# select names('foo%');
   names    
------------
 {foo1,foo}
(1 row)
```